# My question turned out to be a rather esoteric typo -- what should I do/what should be done?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, specific-question

I just wrote this question: [Go isn't linking my assembly: undefined external function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25460967/why-isnt-go-linking-my-assembly-properly)

As it turns out, the problem was a single character. Go wants you to use a mid-dot (`·`) instead of a period (`.`) in assembly files. There's a close reason for a "simple typographical error". I don't want to run afoul of anything, but at the same time this is a pretty esoteric problem. You generally don't expect to have to use a mid-dot when programming.

Since the typo is so esoteric is the question in the clear, or should I (or a mod?) do something about the question since it turned out to just a wrong character issue?

Comment: Well, that's quite evil.  Hard to guess what these guys at AT&T where smoking.  Keep it around.  And perhaps embellish, the `∕` character is special too (U+2215).

Comment: So do we vote up/down if we want the question open/closed or the opposite?

Comment: @user You vote up if you think this question is clear, useful, and shows evidence of research effort. You vote down if you disagree with one or many of those things. You might also vote this question down if you think this is altogether a non-issue, that Jsor shouldn't be worrying about his old questions or cleaning up the site, and that this question is just wasting our time. (Obviously I don't think that applies here, but there *are* questions where it does.) You could also vote it down if you think the presentation of this question is problematic, like it is a rant (which it isn't).

Comment: That's by no means a _simple_ typographical error. Seems more like extremely bad language design - not only is it confusing, how do you even type that on a US keyboard (or on my german one)? I think this is a valid question as it is extremely unintuitive, and certainly different from all of the questions answerable with "you forgot a semicolon/closing paren/capitalization" which are closed with the mentioned reason. There's consensus that even wrong indentation in python doesn't fall under this close reason except for very simple cases, and these cases seem much simpler than your issue.

Comment: @HansPassant: 'Tis curious — I was under the illusion that Go was created at Google, not AT&T, albeit by people who once worked at AT&T.

Comment: @Jonathan, the assembler came from Plan 9, a forgotten OS from Bell Labs.

Comment: It should be noted that this close reason hardly ever is used, simply because most posters will delete the question themselves out of embarassment, if it is truly just "a simple typo".  If the OP still thinks the question is valid, then it probably doesn't fall into this category.

Answer (score 72):

If you think the answer to the question might help someone else in the future (for example, when they run into the same problem and go searching for a solution), post a good answer and keep it around.

Otherwise, if it's truly a bone-headed typo, delete the question. Questions that have already received an answer will need a moderator's intervention to delete them. This is because you are essentially nullifying the time spent and the reputation earned by the person who answered your question. We don't take that lightly, and doing it repeatedly would be considered abusive behavior. However, the moderators will generally make an exception if you use the custom flag box to explain your motive of cleaning up the site by removing questions that will never be of help to anyone else.

In this particular case, I [agree with Hans](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269605/my-question-turned-out-to-be-a-rather-esoteric-typo-what-should-i-do-what-sho#comment83811_269605):

> Well, that's quite evil. Hard to guess what these guys at AT&T where smoking. Keep it around. And perhaps embellish, the `∕` character is special too (U+2215).

This is a well-asked question, with a good answer, about an unintuitive problem that is very likely to be useful to others.

But you should consider doing like he suggests and make the question and answer somewhat more *general*, so that it will be helpful to even more people. That will also allow us to close similar questions received in the future as duplicates of that one, which has already received a good answer.

Answer (score 14):

It's a good question with the correct answer. It's not a typographical error. However, revise the title to something more searchable. For example,

> Go isn't linking my assembly: undefined external function.