# Are all "syntax error questions" off-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope, typographical-error

Just came across this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42180074/syntax-error-on-token-exptected) and a comment that claims:

> Syntax errors are off topic here

Is it that easy?

Are all syntax errors automatically within the `a simple typographical error` category?

Comment: [Even some typo questions can be on-topic](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269605/my-question-turned-out-to-be-a-rather-esoteric-typo-what-should-i-do-what-sho). The deciding factor should be not, "is this caused by a typo?", but rather "is this Q&A going to be useful to someone else later, or is it simply caused by a dumb mistake that could have been avoided by taking more care?"

Comment: It is the kind of justification that SO contributors reach for when they can't find a suitable reason in the close vote dialog.  Which is ill equipped to give newbie programmers like that the kind of help they *really* need.  The odds that he'll intend his code correctly the next time will be much higher when he sweated a day or two on finding this one.  So he'll probably do it again, confident that SO will solve it for him.  Not good.

Comment: @HansPassant Could you try to rephrase your statement? I am not getting whether you are saying: "closing out and hot helping" is the "more helpful thing in the end" ... or something else.

Comment: "not helping", yes.  Close-vote with impunity, the reason does not matter.  But SO users can't help being helpful so it doesn't always work.

Comment: What Hans is saying is basically that spoon-feeding someone the answer for trivial syntax errors makes them *lazy*. It makes them less likely to study the code themselves, and more likely to hop on Stack Overflow and expect someone else to do it for them. We're training people to do this by answering their questions. It would be better to close them. See also: [The saga of the help vampire](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251758/why-is-stack-overflow-so-negative-of-late/252077#252077)

Comment: "Is X always Y?" will be always answered with "no", unless you are talking about mathematics. That's the only science where X can always be Y.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

That user seems to have equated typos with all syntax errors. Not all syntax errors are typos; for example, you could get your syntax wrong because [the programming language changed the syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/826948/syntax-error-on-print-with-python-3).

The person that made that claim already [retracted their statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42180074/syntax-error-on-token-exptected#comment71523599_42180074):

> @MartijnPieters sorry, yes - should have been more explicit. – Boris the Spider

Comment: such cases where a syntax error isn't caused by a "typo" are extremely rare, though, aren't they?

Comment: @JanDvorak: [4k Python SyntaxError questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bpython%5d%20syntaxerror%20closed%3ano%20is%3aq) is not 'rare'.

Comment: Yes, and 99.9% of those are bad or misleading. For example, the [9th one in that list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9705982/pythonw-exe-or-python-exe) asks about pythonw.exe vs python.exe, and the error (the same old `print` change) has nothing to do with the topic. Many others in the top 10 boil down to "my cargo cult programming has incorrect syntax and I don't want to read the manual." I'm sure the rest of the results don't get any better - and don't forget the closed/deleted syntax error questions. So no, they're not bad by definition... but it's a _very_ strong correlation.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3: bad != off-topic. My point is that you can't sweep all of those under the 'typo' rug.

Comment: Yes, I generally use the "not a tutorial service" rug or the "duplicate" rug. :P

Comment: @JanDvorak: You may want to ask the C++ community about the _most vexing parse_. Syntax error in one line, because a previous line defined a function where a variable was intended. So it's not just a typo, and not even a local error.

Comment: Sometimes a syntax error arises because the language changes, and sometimes the [language changes](https://hg.python.org/cpython/rev/419ceb531bab) because of a [syntax error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16950394).