# Are typos always off-topic as Q&A?

Tags: discussion, scope

I asked a question about why my SVG wasn't scaling properly when called as an `<img>` even though it *did* scale properly when the (identical) SVG was included inline in HTML.

[On the same page, an inline SVG scales but an SVG embedded as an <img> doesn't - why not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46136149/on-the-same-page-an-inline-svg-scales-but-an-svg-embedded-as-an-img-doesnt#)

Robert Longson - an authority on SVG - responded:

> standalone SVG is case sensitive, html (and therefore SVG embedded in
>   html) is not. The attribute you've written as view**b**ox is correctly
>   written as view**B**ox

Easy when you know it. A very straightforward answer which saved me hours of head-scratching. Ironically the issue that had evaded me was not why the SVG called by the `<img>` didn't work as expected, but why the inline SVG did.

I'll never make this mistake again - now that I know it, it seems trivial to me.

But at the point where I asked, I'd already spent two hours trying different things and had come up empty-handed.

I appreciate Robert's assertion (in his comment) that:

> Typos are off-topic as Q&A.

but I see that this could also be a hugely time-saving Q&A for anyone who found themselves in the same position as myself yesterday evening.

I should underline - I am **more than happy** to delete my question.

I simply wanted to consult the SO meta community before I did so. Thanks.

Comment: It comes down to "how likely is this question to be helpful to other users?"  99% of the time, they are not.

Comment: Yes, I agree. So if the consensus is that this question won't be helpful to other users, I shall delete.

Comment: @Rounin Not all closed questions should be deleted. It will still be helpful for others even if it's closed. Now regarding the question itself, what if another user have `preserveaspectratio` instead of `preserveAspectRatio`, should they post a new question about that? We might end up with many questions that refer to the same root cause.

Comment: Yes, very good point. I have held off deleting, but I have voted to close.

Comment: @MarounMaroun That person will post the question anyway, since they won't find OPs question here.

Comment: comments by 3 people who just want to close questions is not a consensus. Changing the title and the question will definitely make it useful.

Comment: @Oleg That question also has 4 close votes.

Comment: @Tom Which is fine, as it is now I also think that it should be closed. If it will be improved and be about embedded svg not being case sensitive I would've voted to reopen it if I had the rep.

Comment: if the typo can pass undetected and takes 12 hours to debug/figure out with no other way of detection, then it's an interesting typo.

Comment: Closing and deleting are different things. Just because a question is closed doesn't necessarily mean it should be deleted.

Comment: @RobertLongson Yes, but if it's closed without an answer it's not going to be helpful to anyone in the future (it will in this case because of your comment but it's not reliable and an explicit answer will be much better).

Comment: I can't think of any, but now would be a perfect time for a canonical "tags attributes name case sensitivity" question to appear. I've encountered the problem with angular attributes as well.

Comment: Blanket assertions are always useless.™

Comment: I didn't know the answer to that question and I am a web dev, sure, I have not done much with SVG scaling but when I came to do more that question would have helped me and stopped me from losing the little hair I have left. You don't expect something as crazy as case sensitivity in a modern web standard

Comment: @Sammaye, this is not only true for `viewBox`, but for all SVG markup. So except if you really had this problem caused by the same exact attribute, you would never have found this Q/A (or OP would probably have found  [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14960107) [of these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45996892/) [other ones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39507170/) before asking his question.

Comment: [No, not all questions that arose from a typo are off-topic](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269605/my-question-turned-out-to-be-a-rather-esoteric-typo-what-should-i-do-what-sho). Only the ones that are unlikely to ever be useful to anyone else in the future. In this case, what you should *probably* do is edit the question to be a bit more general, so that it can be used as a general reference to case-sensitivity in SVG.

Comment: Yep, especially when, as it turns out, this is only a typo in some circumstances and not in others!

Comment: If the question is to be edited to be more generalised you should consider what people might search for. Remember the OP did not realise it was a typo / case sensitivity issue at the point of writing, so wouldn't have searched for those terms. So they are useless in the title

Comment: A typo is when you misspell something while typing e.g. teh.    Not knowing that something is case sensitive is a different issue. You didn't make  a mistake in typing since you did not know about it. I think maybe make it into  a question where the answer is about the general issue of case sensitivity for SVG.

Comment: I knew that SVG (as a subset of XML) is case-sensitive. I did not know the attribute is intercapped as _view**B**ox_. It's not really a typo. But it _is_ a spelling mistake.

Answer (score 53):

To me this isn't just a typo.  Yes, the root cause is a typo, but the key point to me (and why I would vote for keeping the question) is that:

- It's not just a specific typo, it's a class of typos (wrong case) and
- This particular class of typo is only a problem when included as a stand-alone file, but is not a typo when included in-line.  I.e. some parsers accept it, some don't.

To me, that distinguishes the question (and the answer, which should then be promoted to an answer not a comment) from a "you have a typo in your code" type problems and makes it worth keeping.  It means the question is potentially useful to others in the future, not just to people who made the exact same typo.  And that is the ultimate test: "is this question (and answer) useful to others?"

Answer (score 41):

Typos just aren't that helpful most of the time. Remember, SO tries to help people with coding problems, but typos are localized problems (in addition to them often being [code dumps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/linked/2973202?lq=1)). It's not helpful, for instance, to Google an error message, only to find that you got the same error from a typo that was different. It also prompts spinoffs saying things like "I found this question but the answer didn't work for me!"

Remember, closure isn't a sign of shame. It just means it doesn't need an answer. I would delete the question since it is closed.

As Felix noted, having a canonical question and answer for this problem could be useful. Just make the question specific to that problem (you've got too much code in the current one).

Answer (score 30):

In general, typo questions aren't useful for other readers, can be resolved in comments, then closed as typos & deleted.

But there are cases where pointing them typos out in answers is useful for future readers, because they'll make a mental note that this is an easy trap to fall into (and that is, if the question is concise enough, that doesn't apply to "wall of code" questions / no MCVE, so OP already figured out approximatively where the problem lies)

Some classical examples I've seen a lot:

in C/C++/Java/JavaScript (semicolon after the test (`if`, `while`), making the following statement execute no matter what):

```c
if (a==0); {
    printf("a is 0\n");  // or System.out.writeln :)
}
```

in C/C++/Java (assigning instead of testing, so condition is never true)

```c
if (a=0) {
   printf("a is 0\n");  // or System.out.writeln :)
}
```

In C, mistakingly activating complex numbers `gcc` extension ([printing same float value always](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52120428/printing-same-float-value-always)):

```c
t=(100/(1+2i)); // instead of t=(100/(1+2*i));
```

In C/C++, swapping `!` and `=` in a test, resulting in the left operand taking a boolean value instead of comparison ([yes it's possible (10K+)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49025280/for-not-incrementing-in-c)):

```c
if (i =! j ) {
```

In C/C++/Java (trying to increment/decrement but assign to `+/-1` instead):

```c
a=+1;
a=-1;
```

In C/C++ testing a condition within quotes:

```c
if("delta>0")
```

In C/C++ incrementing `1` instead of `i` (yes, it's possible to do such a mistake, [10k+ only link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48944189/c-lvalue-required-as-increment-operand))

```c
for(int i = 1; i < 13; 1++)
```

in Python (testing instead of assigning, does nothing):

```python
if a:
   b==True
```

In Python (trying to increment/decrement but assign to `+/-1` instead):

```python
a=+1
a=-1
```

In Python, copying/pasting C/C++ code with pre-increment operator gives infinite loop/doesn't loop but is syntaxically correct:

```python
while (a[++i]<0) or (a[--j]>0):
```

In Python assigning to class/function but not calling it:

```python
handle.close
```

(see also an original Python strange-result typo [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155602/class-can-not-deal-with-args-properly), OPs are very creative :))

In Python bad luck typo when defining a dictionary that triggers string concatenation:

```
>>> {"a":"b","composers:componisten" "two":"twee"}
{'a': 'b', 'composers:componistentwo': 'twee'}  # second key is bogus but syntax is OK
```

In Python, trying to open a Windows file without the *raw* prefix, resuting in python interpreting the escape sequences:

```python
with open("C:\tools\a.txt") as f:
```

python wrong way of protecting conditions, leading to an always truthy result:

```python
if [condition1 and condition2]:
```

(seen in [Simple IF statement in Python 2.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48462928/simple-if-statement-in-python-2-7))

Trying to catch several exceptions with `and` (resulting in only the last exception type being catched):

```python
except KeyError and IndexError:
```

Python Ored regex with or operator outside the string ([TypeError from use of "|" in re.search("RE"|"RE"|"RE", string)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49341960/typeerror-from-use-of-in-re-searchrerere-string))

```python
re.search("UP"|"DOWN"|"LEFT"|"RIGHT", moves)
```

Python using `__neq__` instead of `__ne__`: [Why does the != operator not call my '__neq__' method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50001309/why-operator-is-not-calling-neq)

The consequences of those typos is not a clear error message, the code runs, but with very bizarre behaviour.

It's interesting to have canonical Q&As to link to those (specifically) when it happens, maybe create a `canonical-duplicate` tag for quick search.

Those canonical answers should point out the problem, but also *have to explain* how to prevent such errors in the future (Python: use `PyCharm` for early error detection, C/C++: use CppCheck or some verification too, enable all warnings...) so the user doesn't get caught next time.

Comment: all 3 examples are applicable in other programming languages as well

Comment: I recommend adding in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) all such examples, so the mental note can be made *before* asking the question

Comment: @Adelin: feel free to edit my post to add some more languages. I can only vouch for those 2.

Comment: I meant the wording is not accurate. You'll get the incorrect `==` operation for assignment in Java as well, and you'll also meet `if(a==0);{}` in JS, not only in C

Comment: @Adelin right. And C++ as well. Editing.

Comment: *"pointing them out"* - pointing closed questions? Problem with such cases is what they are hard to put properly in Q&A. Means new people will not be able to find them anyway, so they will simply ask new questions, which will be closed, hopefully with comment explaining why, like many other questions. And it's unavoidable.

Comment: I mean "pointing the typos out", sorry.

Comment: These are the sorts of issues I was hoping documentation would catch. The one I was most fond of is a missing `)` causes a syntax error on the next line, so new Python programmers every few days post a question "Why does `print(result)` say `SyntaxError`?" There really does need to be a canonical answer to this sort of issue when it's abundant.

Comment: @TemporalWolf https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46163392/having-trouble-with-syntax-error :)

Answer (score 12):

I strongly disagree with deleting this post. Since not everybody knows what case-sensitivity rules apply to SVG and HTML, this question can help lots of others. The rule about typos being off-topic for Q&A doesn't apply here, as an exception in my opinion, because you're probably not the first nor the last to run into this specific problem (case sensitivity).

This question is not necessarily a question caused by a typo, it's caused by a *misunderstanding*, which (in my opinion) definitely merits its own question on SO. We're here to improve understanding of all programming-related issues, and this is one of them.

Comment: Yeah, but we should adress the *right* problem. the question is too specific. if it were about case-sensitivity of SVG/HTML, the it would be a great question. as its stands, its not.

Comment: The question is too bad to deserve the answer. While there is a rule "don't give an answer in comments", such questions are too *noisy* and useless to others, so that people (including me) give an answer in comments expecting the question to be closed or OP deleting it. How would others will find it? They are unlikely to have same code, same names or same anything, this leads to "nobody will find it".

Answer (score 8):

## **Can someone with the same problem find the question through a Google search?**

That, in my opinion, should be the primary decider for whether or not a question about a typo should be closed.

If no-one can find the question through searching, there's little point to keeping it on the site. The more likely thing that will happen is that it will add to the noise for people having other problems, making it more difficult to find what they're looking for.

One needs to be able to be find the question through a reasonable search for such a question to be useful.

The determining factors of this are as follows:

- **Does the typo always give the same error / behaviour?**
- **Is that error / behaviour specific to the typo?**

  If the behaviour is going to be vastly different between different instances of the typo, it's very unlikely to be found through searching.

  The same applies if the error is generally always the same, but it's a really common and non-specific error that can apply to many issues (in which case a canonical question on the error might be useful).
- **Is it a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?**

  A code dump asking "why doesn't my code work?" or "why does my code do weird things?" is not a useful question.

  What could be useful is breaking the code down to the smallest possible example, and then asking a very specific question about the behaviour.

## Some examples of potentially appropriate questions:

(not stolen from anywhere, I swear)

Why does the if-statement block execute even when the condition is false?

```java
if (a==0); { /* ... */ }
// OR
if (a=0) { /* ... */ }
```

Why does increment set the variable to the value instead of incrementing by it?

```java
a =+ 1;
```

Why does assigning to a variable have no effect?

```java
a == 0;
```

---

For your specific question, I'd say asking about that issue is probably fine, even if it's only going to be useful for a really small fraction of users. Although you need to post a shorter example.

Comment: An example of this category of question (in my opionion): my now-closed question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59906399/c-struct-constructor-error-explicit-type-is-missing-int-assumed

Comment: Exactly right. For instance, I got a certain error after writing ": =" instead of ":=", and a Google search for the (somewhat cryptic) error message lead to a closed SO Q&A which gave the explanation. Saved me some time actually.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, typos should be closed and potentially deleted.

It is very unlikely that such a question helps a future visitor. The problem is that the question is an *instance* of a whole *class* of problems.

We have a close reason especially targetting typographical errors. It's appropriate here.

But even better would be to create a canonical question about the case-sensitivity (because that's what the question is really about, and what's the root cause), and dupe-hammer the poor question with the new - canonical question.

Another upside is that any future question with the same kind of typo can also be dupe-hammered with the new canonical question. So not only one, but many problems solved.

Comment: _voting to delete this answer because it contains a typo_