# Am I helping or hurting Stack Overflow's mission?

Tags: discussion, answers

I am very new to this website and coding in general, but I am finding it quite fun to try to answer questions on here that are at or just above my level.

I am able to use them as a learning experience for me as well as maybe giving someone an answer.

My question is am I working against the idea behind SO by answering what is basically low hanging fruit?

Comment: Depends. Low hanging fruit that is duplicated somewhere? (In any case, the mere fact you **ask** means you are likely a mindful enough contributor that, even if you are hurting SO's mission currently, it'll be an easy fix:) )

Comment: I have not been searching, just answering what I could. I will do a search first from now on.

Comment: I'm sure a fair amount of people (including myself) have been guilty of doing the same thing at some point. @Makoto's answer below is useful IMHO. Kudos for reflecting on this though ;) +1

Comment: A quick test is: Am I posting or answering questions that got closed, or am I getting downvotes -> probably hurting. Am I getting upvotes and do the questions I post or answer stay open -> probably helping (not posting as an answer because Makoto's answer is way more specific).

Comment: You'll do fine eventually, you are already thinking about "the Stack Overflow mission" and questioning what you are doing - good for you. There are plenty of people that just keep doing what they want to do because they want to do it, rather than taking a moment to reflect and ask questions.

Comment: I just want to add to what other have said: the fact that you're asking this question means you probably have more awareness of SO's mission than 99.9% of its users, and I can only wish we had more people like you.

Comment: Answering questions at above your level is always nice because you'll learn something when other users tell you why you shouldn't do that way.

Comment: You are more community-minded than I am. I answer questions here as best I can to help the people asking the questions, I don't really care what SO's mission is.

Comment: Go ahead and answer things as you see fit, as long as you are adding useful answers. Duplicates are often very hard to find, can take a while to get closed sometimes, and before they get closed tend to collect bad answers. Better to put a good answer there before the bad answers get traction, even if it is a duplicate. (my opinion of course)

Answer (score 97, accepted):

We've got some room to be objective here.

First and foremost (and I know the system is working against you):  you shouldn't answer questions which might already be answered here.  [SyntaxError: invalid syntax in Python for-loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54619569/syntaxerror-invalid-syntax-in-python-for-loop/54619646#54619646) leaps to mind as a question which is *guaranteed* to have been answered here, and it should be flagged as a duplicate.

Also, don't just answer questions for the sake of answering questions.  https://stackoverflow.com/q/54619392/1079354 (10K+ only because it is now deleted) is **too broad** because they're demanding that we write their code for them.  [I've ranted about this before](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/353940/1079354), but especially since it's so seductively easy in Python, you have to **not fall for this**.

Be mindful of the things you're contributing.  A lot of the basic questions have already been answered, and many of the crummy questions will get cleaned up eventually, which may wind up costing you rep.  It's important for you to be judicious and answer questions which you believe will actually *last*.

That likely means not answering questions which are *truly* beginner.  You may require some more time on the site to really find those questions which aren't so beginner.

Comment: Thank you for this, I have just read your post that you linked. I will stop answering for now as I do not want to add to this problem. I have learnt to write Python almost exclusively from reading this website, maybe some time further in the future I will be in a position to contribute back properly.

Comment: "Also, don't just answer questions for the sake of answering questions." I would rephrase this as, "Don't post answers just for the sake of answering questions," and then mention it's fine to write an answer to anything when you're trying to learn if you don't post it. =) +1 regardless.

Comment: "you shouldn't answer questions which might already be answered here." It's important to consider that it can be exceptionally difficult to find an appropriate duplicate or be aware of duplicates when you are new to the site. I have a gold badge and can Mjolnir questions and I *still* have trouble sometimes finding appropriate duplicates. The sooner new users like @Sirsmorgasboard learn to just Google the question title with `site:stackoverflow.com`, the sooner they can begin to notice and improve duplicates (in addition to just spending time looking at questions).

Comment: @TylerH:  [Yes, I am *painfully* aware of this fact.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/357169/1079354)

Comment: @Makoto Sure; my comment was more for the benefit of OP and other users than grizzled veterans like yourself :-)

Comment: **Too broad** example link 404'd. You might want to edit that.

Comment: @Mat:  It's been since deleted.  You don't have enough rep to see it.  I'll put a disclaimer in, thanks for letting me know.

Comment: To supplement this, one of the easier ways of knowing if a question is worth answering is let it sit for 5-10 minutes first. If it's not accumulating downvotes or comments, it's probably safe to answer. Finding duplicates and knowing what makes a question good can be hard at first, so let others handle that for the time being. Rather than looking only at the front page, go a page or two back to find slightly older questions. Ofc this depends what tags you browse.

Comment: I personally am acutely aware that closing a question as a duplicate is often unhelpful to the asker. When they're unfamiliar with concepts and terminology, they may well not understand the other question and its answer, or see that it's essentially the same question expressed in different language. So I only close as a duplicate if I'm very confident that the OP will recognize it as such.

Comment: @MichaelKay:  I'm curious, what circumstances are unhelpful to the OP?  That may be worth a Meta discussion on its own, but don't be surprised if people *don't* agree with that.

Comment: @Makoto I'm never surprised when people disagree with me, and it doesn't worry me: people are entitled to have different aims in life. When it comes to questions like how patient we should be with people who really shouldn't be coding yet, we all have to find our own approach. But I do hate it when people close a good question on "policy" grounds, e.g. because there was a mediocre answer to the same question 4 years ago. I also hate it when people downvote a question without saying why.

Comment: @MichaelKay:  The latter sounds like a personal problem (and trust me when I tell you there's already enough literature here on Meta to explain *why* it will never happen), but the former is borne of a misunderstanding.  Closing a question as a duplicate is not meant to be an insult, nor is it a dig on the OP.  It is explicitly intended to be *helpful* to the asker, or other people asking the same question (e.g. 'signpost').  It is ***important*** for us to close questions because we don't want to rehash the same old already answered stuff here if a four-year old answer is just as serviceable.

Comment: @MichaelKay:  As I said, these discussion points should be in their *own* Meta question.

Answer (score 19):

A couple more reasons to avoid low hanging fruit:

By answering low quality, duplicate, very narrow questions you're reinforcing the asker's behavior instead of teaching them. If they learn how to research, self-educate, and ask high quality questions, that will benefit everybody including the person who is asking (teach a horse to fish... or whatever).

And while these questions are tempting to answer quickly, how many people will they even reach? Quality questions that can help many people will eventually start to show up frequently in search results, and in the long run you'll gain more reputation and you'll have the satisfaction of knowing that you helped thousands of people instead of just one person who copy-pasted your answer into their code and moved on.

For example in the last year I've only answered 2 questions for a total of 5 upvotes. But I've gained about 3,000 reputation, mostly from older questions that took a little more effort to answer but eventually reached the eyes of many people.

Comment: true that votes on old answers (or questions) of yours is infinitely more satisfying than votes on answers that you just posted

Comment: Teach a man to fish, and all that.

Comment: The saying is "You can teach a man to lead a fish to water but you can't make him drink a horse" [source](http://funnytweeter.com/you-can-teach-a-man-to-lead-a-fish-to-water-but-you-cant-make-him-drink-a-horse/)

Answer (score 19):

I remember being in your shoes when I started on the site, not so long ago (june 2016) so the conditions were comparable in terms of already answered questions and site maturity (unlike in the "golden" 2008-2012 years)

I remember I didn't even care about duplicates or didn't even know about the concept, so from time to time I answered questions, which where then closed as duplicates.

I also remember I tried to fix "debug this code for me" questions by pointing out one-off errors here and then.

Some of my answers were probably deleted with the (bad) question it answered to. You're new, you cannot know perfectly how the system works, you've got the right to learn, and high reputation users duty is to clean up the site/close/delete if they see something that doesn't bring value and remind you that (always with respect of the "be nice" policy)

When you start here, it's difficult to get a global picture. Some advice:

- Stay away from questions with a lot of downvotes, questions with walls of code
- Don't answer typo questions, "answered" in comments unless the typo isn't that obvious / has weird effects (see: [Are typos always off-topic as Q&A?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356342/are-typos-always-off-topic-as-qa))
- Google the title of the answer (using `site:stackoverflow.com` in the request to filter it) to see if there's not a duplicate lying around. If you find a duplicate, post a comment so other users can vote/close
- When you're writing your answer, check comments below the question in the meanwhile like "possible duplicate of ...". If the question is a possible/exact duplicate, just quit answering and move on.
- Avoid answering as fast as possible ([the "Fastest Gun In the West" problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem)). Instead, try to provide with a good, documented answer (unless you can answer very fast and with great quality, of course)

Ask yourself this before you answer:

- is the question clear enough to be answered without guessing ?
- is that question title googlable and general enough to interest more than the original poster ?
- does that question has some "replay value" for future users ?

Not all conditions must be met (there are a lot of 0-score accepted answers and even a "unsung hero" badge - which I own - so sometimes helping the original poster only is accepted) but you'll get more votes on a question that interests more people

You can also try to answer some old questions with updated features the answers aren't mentionning / or because you're an expert and none of the answers are satisfying. Your answers then land in a special "late answers" review queue so they are scrutinized: polish them!

After a while, you'll know your duplicates and you'll feel when to answer and when not to. And even after a lot of experience on the site, it happens to answer bad questions from time to time. Other people will remind you that with negative feedback. In that case, you still have the "delete" button.

Comment: I joined in 2011. There was a lot of complaining about low quality questions back then as well. Didn't feel like a golden year ;). This is a good answer though. I learned something new.