# What's best way to handle Questions centered around obvious Syntax or Logical Errors

Tags: support, flags, close-reasons, vote-to-delete

How does SO handle Questions that are centered on obvious Syntax or Logical Errors usually by the asker?

Though some of these questions can be useful if they are common beginner mistakes or stem from a widely misunderstood concept.

But I'm talking of the obvious mistakes like
- omitting a closing brace.
- using undeclared and undefined variables.

Sometimes, these errors get pointed at in the comments section and are resolved under 5mins tops. For instance see this ([onclick creating new javascript object every time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57635388/onclick-creating-new-javascript-object-every-time)).

So, what does SO do or advise users to do.
- Does SO close or clean up these questions?
- Does SO advise users to close or remove these questions.
- If these questions do add to the body of knowledge (for instance identifying common programmers' mistake), how does SO determine that? Does SO recommend flagging such question?
- Is there any other way SO handles this or advises users to handle it.

**UPDATE**

This is no duplicate of this ([Are typos always off-topic as Q&A?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356342)). I've gone through it. Here, the asker even obliges to delete the question. Mine is a more general case. Sometimes, the asker is adamant (even after the error is pointed out in comments) and the question keeps getting answers. See this for example ([TypeError: Cannot read property of value between two getJSON functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57631278/typeerror-cannot-read-property-of-value-between-two-getjson-functions)). Sadly, I was unguided and I answered the question with a deserving down vote :).

So, my question is in order to help users (asker and answerer) take  decisive steps on such questions. I'm not considering only whether to flag or not. I want a more general and complete guide (including flagging) for asker and answerer.

Comment: There is nothing more “complete”. Flag/vote to close; comment if you want.

Comment: @yivi, can't the asker be guided on whether to delete or not after problem is solved in the FAQ for instance?

Comment: I don’t believe that kind of comment is useful. And may lead to arguments. Just let the system work and let the user make their own decisions.

Answer (score 7):

There is a close reason for this kind of question:

> This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting.

These questions should be flagged or voted to be closed; and eventually deleted.

Commenting to help the asker is perfectly fine though; most of the time the user will realize it was the kind of mistake it’s not useful to keep around and delete the question of their own volition.

We have all been there at least once. Or maybe twice. Or thrice.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with yivi that using the "can't repro" flag / close vote is the correct way to handle the question, itself.

However, I (and many others in the tags I frequent) do also post a *comment* explaining the error and how to fix it. We're getting so *many* beginners these days...

Answer (score 0):

IDEs are enough smart to indicate that *we are missing closing brace and variable is not defined.* StackOverflow is **not** for that kind of questions (IMO).

*Deleting/Flagging* depends on the question and decision should be made on how valuable will it be for SO

We can have the [Highly Voted Syntax Error Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/826948/syntax-error-on-print-with-python-3) where syntax has been changed according to version.( Example:  Python 3 valid syntax is `print("Hello World")` instead of `print "hello World"` ). This kind of questions can be helpful.

we can have questions where one small change can solve the issue. which might be helpful for future readers of SO then keep it. For example, [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57519676/restrict-put-delete-and-options-request-in-springboot/57543076#57543076) removing `super.configure(http);` solves the issue. Keeping that kind of questions will be helpful.

Comment: Total beginners can't always interpret an (oder) IDE that only says "Syntax error".